# why does typescript throw error about static definition

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I was gonna use statics in mongoose with typescript but typescript does not understand this static.

I found the type definition from website and it said like this

```
import { Document, model, Model, Schema } from "mongoose";

var UserSchema = new Schema({});
UserSchema.statics.static1 = function () {
  return "";
};

interface IUserDocument extends Document {}
interface IUserModel extends Model<IUserDocument> {
  static1: () => string;
}

var UserModel: IUserModel = model<IUserDocument, IUserModel>(
  "User",
  UserSchema
);
UserModel.static1(); // static methods are available
```

yes it worked before I set something in the Document{}

```
import { Document, model, Model, Schema } from "mongoose";

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 50,
  },
});
UserSchema.statics.static1 = function () {
  return "";
};

interface IUserDocument extends Document {
  name: string;
}
interface IUserModel extends Model<IUserDocument> {
  static1: () => string;
}

var UserModel: IUserModel = model<IUserDocument, IUserModel>(
  "User",
  UserSchema
);
UserModel.static1(); // Property 'static1' is missing in type 'Model<IUserDocument>' but required in type 'IUserModel'
```

I don't know why this weird problem occurred... please help me

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved the problem of it by myself. If there is anyone who experience my case, check this.

If you go to the model's definition, you can see that

```js
export function model<T extends Document, U extends Model<T>>(
    name: string,
    schema?: Schema<T, U>,
    collection?: string,
    skipInit?: boolean
  ): U;
```

The thing you should focus on is that "schema:Schema<T,U>"

it means that the second argument of model() should takes that two definition

so, before you set the schema, you should define that

"const userSchema : mongoose.Schema<T extends Document,U extends Model> = newSchema({})"

And finally, I can avoid this horrible error.